# In Store Pickup delivery Method is not displayed on 2.4.3-p1

Tags: magento2

I have followed all the steps in the guideline below URL

"https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/shipping/shipping-in-store-delivery.html",

"https://store.magenest.com/blog/magento-in-store-pickup/"

but the in-store delivery method is still not displayed in the frontend.

I am using version 2.4.3-p1. I have set "Offline Calculation"  and downloaded Import geocodes
using below command bin/magento inventory-geonames:import us ca gb de